# How to capture error message from one step in another step of an Agent job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Is it possible to capture error message from one step in another step of a SQL Server Agent job?

I have below scenario:

```
Step 1: Transact-SQL script (TSQL)
-- On Success action: Go to step 2
-- On Failure action: Go to step 3
Step 2: Transact-SQL script (Send success email)
Step 3: Transact-SQL script (Send failure email)
```

What I need is, if `step 1` fails, I need to capture error message from `step 1` in `step 3` and send the same in an email notification.

I tried to use below token in Job step, but no success.

`declare @err_msg as nvarchar(4000) = $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(A-MSG))`

Comment: why do not try capture errors and send them inside a single TSQL script?

Comment: What error message are you receiving when trying to use the Token in your script? Have you checked the job history?

Comment: You can capture your errormessage in a table, and then build your e-mail in step 3 through consulting the errormessages table

Comment: @George.Palacios there is no error message, getting blank

Comment: Is Step 1 definitely failing?

Comment: Have you completed the steps in the "Understanding Using Tokens" of this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be querying the [`msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobhistory-transact-sql) table in the job step to get the information you're looking for.

Here's an example query that will get you all runs for a given job (mashed together from these two MSSQLTips articles [[ref1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1752/analyzing-sql-agent-job-and-job-step-history-in-sql-server/)], [[ref2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2850/querying-sql-server-agent-job-history-data/)]).  Obviously, you'll want to adjust this to fit your means, but this should provide you with sufficient direction to get what you want.

```
SELECT j.NAME AS 'JobName'
    ,s.step_id AS 'Step'
    ,s.step_name AS 'StepName'
    ,msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) AS 'RunDateTime'
    ,((run_duration / 10000 * 3600 + (run_duration / 100) % 100 * 60 + run_duration % 100 + 31) / 60) AS 'RunDurationMinutes'
    ,CASE h.run_status
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeded'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Cancelled'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'In Progress'
     END AS ExecutionStatus
    ,h.message MessageGenerated
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s ON j.job_id = s.job_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h ON s.job_id = h.job_id
    AND s.step_id = h.step_id
    AND h.step_id <> 0
WHERE j.enabled = 1 --Only Enabled Jobs
    and j.name = 'JobNameHere'
ORDER BY JobName
    ,RunDateTime DESC
```

Comment: done same thing to achive desired result

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SSIS or is your job running a TSQL script?  You question asks about SSIS but your steps imply TSQL?

If it's a script, I'd have thought that a simple TRY CATCH block would be a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: I believe it's actually a SQL Server agent job, based on the description; that matches how those work.

Comment: David do you mean: Step 1 includes Try-Catch and the Catch stores data about the error in a table.  Step 3 just reads the data from the table.

Comment: I was more just thinking of doing away with step 3 and having the email sent from within the CATCH block?